# Check if variable exists in Logstash

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to write a new logstash filter for events coming from Wazuh. Generally all events set a "%{[rule][description]}" variable and I write this into my alert field. I'm finding that one event is not populating this variable so when I write it to my alert field, I just get %{[rule][description]} instead of the contents.

Does anyone know how to check if a variable exists in a logstash filter? It's fairly easy for fields but not for a variable from what I can gather so far. I'd like to be able to say if the variable doesn't exist, then set it to a string of my choosing.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty strange getting a rule with the rule.description field empty, could you share with me the rule's id?

Anyway, the filter you are looking for is the following one:

```
filter{
    if [rule][description] == '' {
        mutate {
          add_field => [ "rule.description", "VALUE" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where you can fill VALUE with the string you wish.

Hope it helps.